# Measuring two arrays for equality of lowest numbers

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL Tables:

```
 create table events (
  sensor_id integer not null,
  event_type integer not null,
  value integer not null,
  time timestamp unique not null
 );
```

And it looks something like this:

```
 sensor_id  | event_type | value      | time


 -----------+------------+------------+--------------------
  2          | 2          | 5          | 2014-02-13 12:42:00
  2          | 4          | -42        | 2014-02-13 13:19:57
  2          | 2          | 2          | 2014-02-13 14:48:30
  3          | 2          | 7          | 2014-02-13 12:54:39
  2          | 3          | 54         | 2014-02-13 13:32:36
```

what is the easiest way to return the most recent value in terms of time by sensor_id and event_type? so it looks like this:

```
sensor_id  | event_type | value


-----------+------------+-----------
  2          | 2          | 2
  2          | 3          | 54
  2          | 4          | -42
  3          | 2          | 7
```

I cant get my head around it

Answer (score 2):

try the t-sql code below:

```
SELECT e.sensor_id, e.event_type, e.value
FROM
    (SELECT e.sensor_id, time = MAX(e.time)
      FROM dbo.events e WITH(NOLOCK)
      GROUP BY e.sensor_id, e.event_type) m
    JOIN dbo.events e WITH(NOLOCK) ON e.sensor_id = m.sensor_id
        AND e.time = m.time
ORDER BY e.sensor_id
```

how are your sorting the rows? can't seem to see the pattern.

EDIT: got the sorting now!

```
SELECT e.sensor_id, e.event_type, e.value
FROM
    (SELECT e.sensor_id, time = MAX(e.time)
      FROM dbo.events e WITH(NOLOCK)
      GROUP BY e.sensor_id, e.event_type) m
    JOIN dbo.events e WITH(NOLOCK) ON e.sensor_id = m.sensor_id
        AND e.time = m.time
ORDER BY e.sensor_id, e.sensor_id + e.event_type
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to do:

```
SELECT value FROM events WHERE sensor_id=? AND event_type=? ORDER BY time DESC
```

Then the first one is the most recent.

Databases can sometimes limit you to just one, depending on the database you want.

I put a question mark where you would need to put a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    sensor_id, event_type, value
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
            (PARTITION BY sensor_id, event_type ORDER BY time DESC) AS Ordering, 
        * 
    FROM events
) data
WHERE
    data.Ordering = 1
```